# How to send HTML via JSON to an Angular app in Rails?

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails, json, angularjs

In my Rails app I have a model text_snippet which is associated with work. Text_snippets contain html in the "body" attribute. What I was trying to do was to create a view app/views/work/show.json.erb

```
{"snippets": [<% @work.text_snippets.each do |ts| %><% unless  ts == @work.text_snippets.last %>"<%= j ts.body %>",
<% else %>"<%= j ts.body %>"<% end %><% end %> ]}
```

And then parse it in an Angular controller

```
kleApp.controller('KleWorkCtrl',function($scope,$routeParams,$http,$sce){
$http.get('http://localhost:3001/works/' + $routeParams.workId + '.json').success(function(data) {
    $scope.work = data;
$scope.snippets = $scope.work.snippets;

});
```

});

and show it in Angular view

```
      <div ng-repeat="snippet in work.snippets"><span ng-bind-html="snippet"></span></div>
```

However I'm getting constantly "unexpected token" error.

Comment: Have you checked how your {"snippets":[...array...]} is rendered? Is it having the right syntax?

Comment: Of course! Silly mistake. The json I was outputting from rails was invalid.

Comment: Maybe you should look at jbuilder gem...

Comment: I surely will. As many people have already mentioned erb templates are not terribly well suited for json. Just needed something quickly.